# PULSE Elite Headset & Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

Can I use the PULSE Elite headset for voice chat on the Xbox 360? I know it connects to the PlayStation via USB, and can connect to other devices by linking a 3.5 mm cable to the USB dongle. Is the dongle directly compatible with the Xbox? If not, is there another way to connect it in such a way that will allow voice chatting with the built-in microphone while also getting game and chat audio through the headphones?

---

Some testing so far indicates that the dongle is not at all Xbox-compatible. It can use the Xbox for power, but that's it - won't even output sound to the headphones without any other attachment. I've successfully tested the PULSE Elite as a wired headset for my phone, so it may just be a matter of getting an adapter for the standard 3.5 mm plug to go to the 2.5mm jack on the controller.

---

Further research seems to indicate that if I do manage to get it working through the controller, it will only be handling voice chat audio - no game audio output there. That would be a fair buzz-kill, if it can't be worked around.